# Backup domain controller with exchange remove it?

Tags: windows, exchange-server, domaincontroller

So in my network I have the main domain controller and a backup domain controller. The backup domain controller has exchange on it.

The exchange services have been shut down as I have moved email hosting off site. So I now have no need of that backup domain controller that was running exchange. I want to shut it down for good.

What would be the proper way to remove it from its role in active directory and a backup domain controller?

Both domain controllers are Server 2008.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, just don't do it, this is a SysAdmin SIN! Your shooting yourself in the foot. Even for my smallest customers with only 10 members of staff, I often have them purchase a second server to act as a secondary domain controller, DNS server, DHCP Server etc.

It is the first and few things Microsoft recommends as best practice when setting up a domain and one of the first things that is taught to you when you do the MCSA course: When creating a domain a secondary domain controller should be set up. If you have more than 20 Users its a must IMHO. Many things can go wrong and too many times clients have incurred big bills(man hours) because they didnt spend that extra £2000 on another server. I strongly recommend you keep it. It's not just availability, it prevents a large number of corruption issues which can linger for weeks before presenting themselves which makes 7x daily backups no help. It's your sefety net.

If you must get rid of it, first check is doesn't hold the FSMO roles and run dcpromo following the steps here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771844(v=ws.10).aspx

Lastly, your getting down-voted because StackOverflow only like coding qustions and they want you to use ServerFault which is part of the same family.